# I want to sort by the first element of a tuple which is in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I want to know how I can sort by the bigger element (which is here the int 7):

```
{'a': (2, 0, 'a'), 'b': (4, 0, 'b'), 'c': (7, 0, 'c')}
```

In my entire code the sorting is done in a 'while'

Thank you.

Comment: For "sorting" a dictionary see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly that you want to sort by the first item in the value tuple:

```py
d = {'a': (2, 0, 'a'), 'b': (4, 0, 'b'), 'c': (7, 0, 'c')}

sorted_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][0], reverse=True))
# {'c': (7, 0, 'c'), 'b': (4, 0, 'b'), 'a': (2, 0, 'a')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can't be sorted, unless you're fine with it not being a dictionary anymore. Otherwise, it can be done with a single line of code.

```
new_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)
```

`data.items()` contains (key, value) pairs. The `key` argument indicates what we're sorting over, and in this case, it's the zeroth index of the value tuple (`x[1]`). Since you want the highest value at the top, we set the `reverse` argument to `True`.

Output:

```
[('c', (7, 0, 'c')), ('b', (4, 0, 'b')), ('a', (2, 0, 'a'))]
```

Comment: they can now ... sorta kinda. They'll remember order of insertion, which you can set according to a sort key when you replace it with a new dict object.